# Missing cyg*.dll when using libraries compiled with Cygwin, and errors when added

Tags: c++, dll, cygwin, mingw, zlib

I just compiled zlib and libzip with Cygwin to use them with Code::Blocks in Windows.
My code is that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zip.h>

int main()
{
    //Open the ZIP archive
    int err = 0;
    zip *z = zip_open("main.zip", 0, &err);
    zip_close(z);

    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I build my code, it works well, no errors and warnings.

When I launch my program, it says that I don't have cygzip-2.dll. Okay, I search it and put it in my executable folder. Then, it says that I don't have cygwin1.dll. Okay, I put it too. The same for cygz.dll and cyggcc_s-1.dll.

Oh, it works! But then, my program stops with always the same status: -1073741819.
It doesn't even tell me hello :(

I compiled it with MinGW (it did the same error on Cygwin), and I linked libz.a, libzip.a and libzip.dll.a. Where does the problem could come from?

Thanks!

EDIT: When I try to compile my program *IN* Cygwin, it says 'undefined reference to '_zip_open'' and 'undefined reference to '_zip_close''. Probably something is missing, but what?

Comment: Possible crash? Have you tried running in a debugger? Have you checked that you actually get a valid pointer back from `zip_open`?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't try to check the pointer, but I'll do it as soon as possible. And what do you mean by running in a debugger? Make a debug executable? I'm pretty new in C++, and I don't know all those functions.

Comment: Okay, I didn't succeed what the function returned, but when I try to compile my program *IN* Cygwin, it says 'undefined reference to '_zip_open'' and 'undefined reference to '_zip_close''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I succeeded to use my 2 libraries! I had already tried to use CMake, but failed miserably.

So today, I decided to retry it with the GUI. Firstly, I compiled zlib. I chose the zlib folder, and put the build folder in it. I configured with the option for Code::Blocks and MinGW Makefiles, and native compilers. Then, I opened the .cbp (Code::Blocks Project) in my 'build' folder, and built it.

For libzip, I did the steps except that I specified 2 variables:

ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR = the root of zlib folder (where there are all the .h and .c) and ZLIB_LIBRARY = [the path to your build folder from zlib]\libzlib.dll

I built it from the .cbp too. And I linked all my files to my project, and it was done!